# Where can I find complete multilingual in-game dialogue transcripts?

Tags: localization, dialogue-tree

I'd like to do some  linguistic analysis.

It doesn't matter if it's a AAA title or not; the requirement is only that it should be the complete transcript from the official game and that it's available in multiple languages.

Answer (score 2):

Try open-source visual novels. The writing is typically rough around the edges, but there is plenty of it. Such games are frequently translated by fans.

<sub>(Watch out, contents may be, uh, *steamy*.)</sub>

If they're made in [Ren'Py](http://www.renpy.org/), a Python-based VN engine ([many are](http://games.renpy.org/)) then their dialogue will be findable in human-readable form in the distribution.

[Juniper's Knot](http://junipersknot.dischan.org/?l=en), for example has [been](http://junipersknot.dischan.org/?l=pt) [translated](http://junipersknot.dischan.org/?l=ru) [into](http://junipersknot.dischan.org/?l=fr) [various](http://junipersknot.dischan.org/?l=id) [languages](http://junipersknot.dischan.org/?l=it).

Answer (score 1):

It will vary from game to game. Some games will have this information easily accessible in human readable data files, other games will have it stored in binary data packages. This is something you'll just have to poke around and find yourself depending on which game you're interested in. Either by looking through the data files yourself, or searching online for someone that's found the information already.

There are likely easier ways to get transcripts in multiple languages. For example, movie subtitles are frequently available in multiple languages.